# Dispay text message to be read from a file in sd card

Tags: android, sd-card

I want to display a text message, after reading it from a text file on the sd card. I also want to include two buttons in the message for taking user confirmation.

The solutions provided in this forum for similar questions were not of much use to me. Also the documentation in android website was not easily understandable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please try to ask specific questions, not "how to make a simple android app?", i would advise you to start with the layout and the two buttons you want to show in your application, it is well documented in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: What do you need help with? Reading from SD card, displaying dialog or both?

Comment: Yes I want to do both. I want to read text from a file in sd card and display it in a dialog with buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on the following url to read a text file from sdcrd. after agetting the text you can use textview to set display the text

[How to read a text file from SDCard](http://www.anddev.org/read_a_txt_file_from_sd_card_in_a_real_device-t6619.html)

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to define, what a "text message" means.

Reading a text file is not android specific: just use the Java API for working with files.

if you're new to (Android) programming: buy a book and learn from it.